# Pandas Transform on each group dataframe (performance)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset and I need to perform some calculations on it. This is a sample of it:

```
id         group_id        start_date   end_date
45891167   00000dc8-b87e   2017-09-14   2017-12-15
45891167   00000dc8-b87e   2017-12-15   2018-03-18
50692679   000012e9-e137   2018-03-29   2019-03-05
50692679   000012e9-e137   2019-03-05   2019-03-27
50692679   000012e9-e137   2019-03-27   2019-04-05
51622620   000011e5-e107   2021-03-15   NaT
81652621   000019e1-e111   2020-06-15   2020-06-19
81652621   000019e1-e111   2020-07-16   NaT
```

I want the transformed df to look like this (see below). The logic I wanted to apply is the following: if the difference between the `end_date` of the prior value and the `start_date` of the current value is higher than 20 days set `start_date` as the row's `start_date`. If not use `start_date` of the prior row. This logic should be applied for each `group_id`.

```
id         group_id        start_date   end_date    first_date    
45891167   00000dc8-b87e   2017-09-14   2017-12-15  2017-09-14
45891167   00000dc8-b87e   2017-12-15   2018-03-18  2017-09-14
50692679   000012e9-e137   2018-03-29   2019-03-05  2018-03-29 
50692679   000012e9-e137   2019-03-07   2019-03-27  2018-03-29
50692679   000012e9-e137   2019-03-27   2019-04-05  2018-03-29
51622620   000011e5-e107   2021-03-15   NaT         2021-03-15
81652621   000019e1-e111   2020-06-15   2020-06-19  2020-06-15
81652621   000019e1-e111   2021-07-16   NaT         2021-07-16
```

I have created this transformation logic to get the expected input. The issue is the original dataset has over 1M distinct `group_id` and by using the for loop it seems this approach isn't going to be performant.

```
for group in df['group_id'].unique():
    indexes = (df.loc[df['group_id'] == group]).index.tolist()

    df['end_date_previous_row'] = (df.loc[df['group_id'] == group])['end_date'].shift(1)

    if len((df.loc[df['group_id'] == group]).index) == 1:
        df['first_date'] = (df.loc[df['group_id'] == group])['start_date']
    else:
        for idx, row in (df.loc[df['group_id'] == group]).iterrows():
            if idx == indexes[0]:
                df.loc[idx, 'first_date'] = df.loc[idx, 'start_date']
            else:
                difference = row['start_date'].to_pydatetime() - row['end_date_previous_row'].to_pydatetime()
                df.loc[idx, 'difference'] = difference
                if difference.days >= 20:
                    df.loc[idx, 'first_date'] = df.loc[idx, 'start_date']
                else:
                    df['first_date'].fillna(method='ffill', limit=1, inplace=True)
```

Is there a more performant approach? Maybe using `groupby` and `transform`?

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is use `groupby` with `transform`

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
g = df.groupby('id')
s = (df['start_date'] - g['end_date'].shift()).dt.days>=20
df['first_date '] = g['start_date'].transform('first').mask(s,df['start_date'])
Out[921]: 
0   2017-09-14
1   2017-09-14
2   2018-03-29
3   2018-03-29
4   2018-03-29
5   2021-03-15
6   2020-06-15
7   2020-07-16
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions: `.transform('first')` is it just a random name for this transformation? and `g.end_date.shift()).dt.days>=20` what is `g`? Should it be `df`?

Comment: @mcortez4790 check the update

Comment: @BENY I think the confusion there might be you're mixing item access and attribute access... so that `df.start_date` looks like it might be something different than `df['start_date']` is... (and they're actually doing something different or behave differently kind of thing)

Comment: @JonClements you are right ~ change all to '', since this will fit all name condition

Comment: And although they look from the sample data they're synonymous - think the OP mentioned explicitly `group_id` instead of `id`... for some weird reason... rows 3-6 seem to have shifted their id's to be prefixed with 12 instead of 50... between their sample input and output? :p

Comment: EDIT: Copy/paster error Jon! Id's shouldn't change! The only thing that should added is the new column `first_date ` based on the condition I specified above